# What does an 'empty' return return

Tags: language-agnostic, return

Question in the code comments:

```
   function find($id, Application_Model $guestbook)
        {
            $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
            if (0 == count($result)) {
                return;  // what is returned in functions like these?
        }
```

Comment: Is "theory" a programming language similar to PHP?

Comment: @Barmar It looks like the tag is usually used to refer to CS theory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/theory

Comment: @Sancho Which suggests that he's looking for a language-agnostic answer, which doesn't really exist for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) says "If no parameter is supplied ... NULL will be returned." So this:

```
return;
```

is equivalent to:

```
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return anything. That said, if you try to assign the output of that function to a variable, then that variable will be `null`.

```
function iDoNothing()
{
    return;
}

$returnValue = iDoNothing();
// $returnValue is now null
```

Answer (score 0):

Return statements with no argument return null.

You can try this yourself by creating a short php script:

```
<?php
  echo emptyReturn();

  function emptyReturn() {
    return;
  }
?>
```

Comment: var_dump() would fit better here

Comment: nor echo or print could fit what you are trying to accomplish. One should use `print_r();`, `var_dump()` or `var_export()`.

Comment: Ah yes, I agree with both of you. I was calling from javascript making my php not very helpful by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually dependent on the language. Here's a list for a few of them ("if value omitted, return" column): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement

In the case of PHP, it simply returns `NULL`.

In a language like C/C++, the behavior is undefined. Meaning it could return junk information.
This is why languages like Java prevent you from doing this. Java will give you a compiler error if you try to `return;` within a non-void function.

Edit: Actually that Wikipedia page didn't really have much info on this, so I added some to it.